# Запустить задачу в фоне php

Tags: php, backgroundworker

Есть веб-интерфейс, куда юзер загружает файл и файл процессится. Нужно чтобы после загрузки началась обработка файла и пользователь в реальном времени мог видеть что происходит. Даже если он закроет броузер и потом вернется на страницу, то он должен опять-таки созерцать процесс работы скрипта. Как этого достичь, ведь по понятным причинам, если я загружу файл и переда его скрипту напрямую, то он будет работать и показывать пустую страницу пользователю, пока не закончит. Так же он прекратит работу, если пользователь закроет страницу. Решение хотелось бы платформонезависимым. Спасибо.

UPD: Нашел подходящее решение под вин: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289595/starting-a-windows-process-in-php-and-get-its-pid

Большое спасибо всем, кто ответил!

Comment: После загрузки файла можно запустить процесс через ajax. Тогда процесс будет идти даже если пользователь закроет окно. Ну а чтобы показывать прогресс, можно регулярно делать дополнительные ajax запросы.

Comment: @cyadvert, я с аяксом в общем-то никогда не работал, в этом вопросе полный нубас. То есть, если я аяксом обращусь к скрипту, то запрос сразу вернет какой-нибудь ответ, даже если скрипт еще работать долго будет? Немного не понял.

Comment: не, совсем. запрос вернется, когда скрипт закончит работу. Но пока он работает - Ваша страница функионирует нормально... Однако, если посетитель уйдет со страницы на другую,узнать статус посланного запроса будет нельзя. Можно будет лишь проверить результат (в базе, или в файлах, в зависимости от того, что скрипт делал)... ну т.е. если скрипт должен был обработать фото и записать его куда-то, второстепенный ajax запрос может спрашивать "создан ли тот файл". Если создан, значит все ОК. Опять же, это в том случае, если посетитель ушел со страницы. Если он все еше на странице - ajax даст ответ.

Comment: @cyadvert, но мне нужно чтобы после запуска процесса, можно было в любой момент узнать его состояние. Во-первых, не ясно как можно запустить в фоне скрипт на выполнении. Дальше там в принципе есть варианты, скрипт пишет в бд по мере выполнения, а аякс обращается к промежуточному скрипту, который показывает состояние, доставая из бд.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал использовать соккет

Comment: Именно это я имел ввиду: "аякс обращается к промежуточному скрипту, который показывает состояние, доставая из бд". Насчет соккетов не знаю. Слышал, что это классно :) Хотел в след. проекте изучить/использовать. Но деталей не знаю.

Comment: @cyadvert, окей, с промежуточным скриптом понятно. Но как решить главное - запустить обработку данных в фоне? Например через exec или system. Но они, опять таки, блокирующие, поэтому не подходят.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин под *nix `system` может быть не блокирующим, т.к. запускает командный интерпретатор (shell) и отдает команду ему. А shell отправляет задачу в фоновое выполнение, если команда оканчивается на `&`. Но порожденная команда умрет вместе с родителем, что бы этого избежать можно использовать `nohup`. И того ваш систем должен быть примерно таким `system("nohup php your-script.php &")`

Comment: @Mike, да, похоже на то что нужно, но как такое реализовать под windows? $cmd = "start  php test.php > C:\\users\\alex\\desktop\\123.txt"; 
pclose(popen($cmd,'w')); Так почему-то ничего в файл не пишется, и не еще неясно как определить, нормально ли запустилась программа, или что-то пошло не так.

Comment: @Mike, nohup в том виде, как Вы его предлагаете будет выводить результаты в файл `nohup.out` / Представляете, что произойдет если еще один запрос придет до того, как выбрали результат предыдущего (аналогично для параллельно выполняемых запросов)?

Comment: @АлександрПушкин, в вашей любимой винде для запуска процессов есть команда `start` (`start /?` нарисует свой help).

Comment: @avp, я знаю, если вы в комментариях посмотрите, я уже упоминал. Только там проблема такая, что либо консоль появляется, либо выводт программы не пишется в файл. И еще нельзя определить, нормально ли произошел запуск скрипта, например (если файла не будет, popen вернет дескриптор).

Comment: @avp А я и не предполагал что php скрипт что то будет выдавать на стандартный вывод ибо ТС говорил, что предполагает передавать результаты через mysql

Comment: @АлександрПушкин, ну так и не пишите в винде, вообще забейте на нее.

Comment: @avp, что значит забейте? Очень профессионально! (сарказм). На буржуйском стаке вроде люди нашли решение, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите в сторону Gearman.

Примерный вариант:

1. Файл отправляется клиентскому скрипту, который ставит его в очередь в Gearman.
2. Воркер обрабатывает файл и сохраняет промежуточные результаты обработки в какой-нибудь сторедж (напр. MySQL).
3. Клиентский скрипт берет данные из стореджа и отдает их клиенту (можно через ajax или обновлением страницы).

Comment: Мб придется, если штатными средствами не получится. Но как-то не охото если честно.

Comment: Есть еще один вариант: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

Comment: @АлександрПушкин это физически невозможно сделать без брокера сообщений. Вы либо напишете его самостоятельно (что крайне не рекомендуется, за исключением чисто академических целей), либо возьмете готовый. Но Gearman я бы не рекомендовал, лучше сразу AMQP.

Comment: @Etki, ну отчасти это решается запуском процесса в фоне, только тут есть нюансы которые меня смущают. Например. не понятно как определить успешность запуска процесса. Ну и вывод в файл у меня в windows не работает c параметром /B.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин запуск процесса в фоне - это только часть всего решения (тоже необходимая). Я потом распишусь ответом, если будет время.

Comment: @Etki ну мне на данный момент больше не требуется. Остальное взаимодействие через БД и аякс будет происходить.

Comment: @Etki, "_Но Gearman я бы не рекомендовал, лучше сразу AMQP_", AMQP -- это не брокер сообщений, а протокол))

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я знаю.